# Katalon cannot click button in Chrome headless

Tags: google-chrome-headless, katalon-studio

[![enter image description here][1]][1]When I launch a test case in Chrome headless it fails because it can't find a button, but when I launch it in Chrome visible it succeeds. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a screenshot and validate, that the element you want to click is visible. Perhaps your screen is with to small size.

Comment: I've added WebUI.takeScreenshot("C:\\foo.png") but it says access denied.

Comment: Now I have put WebUI.takeScreenshot("C:\\Users\\myname\\Pictures\\foo.png") and it has shown me a page that says "you are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers"

Comment: Can you see the report in Katalon Studio? Is it possible to look at the report details and attached screenshot?

Comment: Try just to take screenshot with WebUI.takeScreenshot()

Comment: The screenshot is a page saying: "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized"

Comment: The problem is that normal Chrome executes the integrated authentication meanwhile Chrome headless doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Because Chrome headless doesn't perform integrated authentication. At least by default.

Comment: Is there a solution to this?